# Mechanize - Python Issue

Tags: javascript, ajax, post, mechanize-python

I was just trying to explore Mechanize. I just started learning about it yesterday.

**Just to be clear, I am doing this for just learning purposes, and not any intentions of breaking and all. This is just for learning purposes. I simply chose this site, because it uses AJAX / Javascript (which this site ses in particular, I am not sure of), otherwise there were 100 other sites that I could have chosen from. So, please help me in learning this.**

So, I just came across this webpage - [www.snapdeal.com](http://www.snapdeal.com) . If you correctly notice this web page, and if you click on the 'Register' link, in the drop-down that comes on clicking the 'Account' button, and then on the 'Register using email' link, you'll notice that the website probably uses either Javascript or AJAX (I am not sure, which one does this website use) to display the 'Register using email' Form.

I just managed to enter some data in the 'Register using email form', and managed to get these results-:

**1.** Then I just managed to track the POST Request that the website sends when the Register button is clicked, in the 'Register using email' form. Here are all the details associated with it-:

**1.a.** These are the Request Headers-:

```
POST /signupAjax HTTP/1.1
Host: www.snapdeal.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Referer: https://www.snapdeal.com/iframeLogin
Content-Length: 128
Cookie: u=143332124339995687; __pr.cd2=bvzs4642ht; st=utm_source%3Daffiliate%7Cutm_content%3Dnull%7Cutm_medium%3Dnull%7Cutm_campaign%3Dafts%7Cref%3Dnull%7Cutm_term%3Dnull%7Caff_id%3D13521%7Caff_sid1%3Dnull%7Caff_sid2%3Dnull%7C; lt=utm_source%3DSEO%7Cutm_content%3Dnull%7Cutm_medium%3Dnull%7Cutm_campaign%3Dnull%7Cref%3Dnull%7Cutm_term%3Dnull%7Caff_id%3Dnull%7Caff_sub%3Dnull%7Caff_sub2%3Dnull%7C; hpcl=616%7C53%7C288%7C257%7C175; hprv=2144302598-288%7C334547072-257%7C650370172861-175; _chartbeat2=BOCWJdBEo9iVCiO94S.1433321252304.1436675591755.0000101001010011; _SPP=SPP.1246344867578.179; _bs=cc770ead-fc2e-9f7e-32f4-87d8e2ee86b6; lang=en; s_pers=%20s_vnum%3D1438797571135%2526vn%253D4%7C1438797571135%3B%20gpv_pn%3DhomePage%253Anew%7C1436677385116%3B%20s_invisit%3Dtrue%7C1436677385119%3B; _cb_ls=1; track=BD%3Dhome; UP=0; JSESSIONID=4A6550703DD561263A67C9DD18D030FB; JSESSIONID=4A6550703DD561263A67C9DD18D030FB; s_sess=%20s_cc%3Dtrue%3B%20s_sq%3D%3B%20s_ppv%3D17%3B; bw=32.32; AWSELB=A9C537B30E076CDBCC1B9998259521F79795C353D1DF2A0435368C6E4768EB61F155147CEA5738409A47064137FA0D9CD3B8721BA4B9E0C8AE32031F93B321F69BF55EC0B0; vt=utm_source%3DDIRECT%7Cutm_content%3Dnull%7Cutm_medium%3Dnull%7Cutm_campaign%3Dnull%7Cref%3Dnull%7Cutm_term%3Dnull%7Caff_id%3Dnull%7Caff_sub%3Dnull%7Caff_sub2%3Dnull%7C; IGFB={"user":{"name":"snapdeal","id":"560252645","count":"4.3k"}}; eid="ada@werwer.comlogoutSuccess=success"; _chartbeat5=
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

**1.b.** These are the POST Parameters-:

```
CSRFToken=02325b364cc453ca796e76b365655b5ff020674e
ajax=true
j_confpassword=1234567
j_password=1234567
j_username=q@ewrwer.xom
```

**1.c.** This is the Location with the parameters-:

```
https://www.snapdeal.com/signupAjax?CSRFToken=02325b364cc453ca796e76b365655b5ff020674e&ajax=true&j_confpassword=1234567&j_password=1234567&j_username=q%40ewrwer.xom
```

**2.** I also managed to track down the request that the website sends to display the registration form. Here are all the details associated with it-:

**2. a.** This is the location-:

```
http://www.snapdeal.com/omn/getOmnitureCode?eventType=RegisterLinkInHeader&
```

**2.b.** These are the Request Headers-:

```
POST /omn/getOmnitureCode?eventType=RegisterLinkInHeader& HTTP/1.1
Host: www.snapdeal.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0
Accept: text/html, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Referer: http://www.snapdeal.com/?logoutSuccess=success
Cookie: u=143332124339995687; __pr.cd2=bvzs4642ht; st=utm_source%3Daffiliate%7Cutm_content%3Dnull%7Cutm_medium%3Dnull%7Cutm_campaign%3Dafts%7Cref%3Dnull%7Cutm_term%3Dnull%7Caff_id%3D13521%7Caff_sid1%3Dnull%7Caff_sid2%3Dnull%7C; lt=utm_source%3DSEO%7Cutm_content%3Dnull%7Cutm_medium%3Dnull%7Cutm_campaign%3Dnull%7Cref%3Dnull%7Cutm_term%3Dnull%7Caff_id%3Dnull%7Caff_sub%3Dnull%7Caff_sub2%3Dnull%7C; hpcl=616%7C53%7C288%7C257%7C175; hprv=2144302598-288%7C334547072-257%7C650370172861-175; _chartbeat2=BOCWJdBEo9iVCiO94S.1433321252304.1436676251573.0000101001010011; _SPP=SPP.1246344867578.179; _bs=cc770ead-fc2e-9f7e-32f4-87d8e2ee86b6; lang=en; s_pers=%20s_vnum%3D1438797571135%2526vn%253D4%7C1438797571135%3B%20gpv_pn%3DhomePage%253Anew%7C1436678066075%3B%20s_invisit%3Dtrue%7C1436678066079%3B; _cb_ls=1; track=BD%3Dhome; UP=0; JSESSIONID=274401F99C991AA1EC8A0A62814589DF; JSESSIONID=274401F99C991AA1EC8A0A62814589DF; s_sess=%20s_cc%3Dtrue%3B%20s_sq%3D%3B%20s_ppv%3D17%3B; bw=32.32; AWSELB=A9C537B30E076CDBCC1B9998259521F79795C353D1DF2A0435368C6E4768EB61F155147CEA5738409A47064137FA0D9CD3B8721BA4B9E0C8AE32031F93B321F69BF55EC0B0; vt=utm_source%3DDIRECT%7Cutm_content%3Dnull%7Cutm_medium%3Dnull%7Cutm_campaign%3Dnull%7Cref%3Dnull%7Cutm_term%3Dnull%7Caff_id%3Dnull%7Caff_sub%3Dnull%7Caff_sub2%3Dnull%7C; IGFB={"user":{"name":"snapdeal","id":"560252645","count":"4.3k"}}; eid=q@ewrwer.xom
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Length: 0
```

Also, when we click on the 'Register using Email' link in the 'Register' popup, I managed to check that no additional GET or POST request was sent by the website.

So, how do I access the 'Register using Email' Form on the website, using Mechanize, or if some additional library is also required (I am saying so, since I just started using Mechanize yesterday, so I don't have that much of an in-sight into it)? So, I am completely open to whichever additional library you use along with Mechanize!

Once I have access to it, I can simply fill it and submit it, Right? Am I correct on this part?

Please provide the complete code for it along with an explaination, since if you just explain things, it will be a bit tough for me, as I started using Mechanize yesterday only. So, preferably, please help with a complete code.

**Again, as I said above, this is for Learning Purposes only. Please don't consider any security violations that I am trying to do. I WANT TO LEARN HOW TO APPLY MECHANIZE ON SUCH WEBSITES (THAT'S THE BIG POINT!).**

Answer (score 0):

You should first check the source code from the website, since Javascript is not supported in Mechanize.

Example for submitting form in Python with Mechanize:

```
import mechanize

EMAIL = "mymail@gmail.com"
PASS = "mypass"

def login(email,password):
    browser = mechanize.Browser()
    browser.set_handle_robots(False)
    browser.open('https://Login-SomeWebsite.com')
    browser.select_form(nr=0)
    browser.form["email"] = EMAIL
    browser.form["pass"] = PASS
    browser.submit()
    return browser
```

Comment: Actually, I managed to check the source code. The 'Register using Email' one form (that is displayed using javascript), was actually also present in the source code when I tried to search for the same id of that 'Register using Email one form' using Firebug in the source code of the home page of snapdeal (where I haven't clicked on the Register link in the Accounts drop down).So basically the form that I want to select has style="display:none" at this stage, and display changes to block when I click on the Register using Email link (as elaborated in the question),so it uses javascript, mostly!

Comment: So, it's basically a form with style="display:none". Now, how do I select that form using MECHANIZE and any other additional library if required?